# How can a string be a boolean value?

Tags: c, string, pointers, while-loop, boolean

```
char **commands = parse_line( input, ';' );
int i = 0;
while ( commands[i]) {
  /* Runs some functions, commands[i] not affected */
  i++;
}
```

Header for `parse_line`

```
char **parse_line(char *line)
```

In the while loop, can `command[i]` actually ever be true?

`char *line` would be something along the lines of `ls -l\n`.

NOTE: `\n` is included due to user having to press `RETURN` after entering a terminal command.

Comment: Think of false as being "equal to 0" and true as "not equal to 0".

Comment: `{delim, '\n'}` --> `{delim, '\0'};`

Comment: Please indent your code properly. This helps everybody reading your code.

Comment: I'm sorry, did I mis-indent? I'm using two spaces instead of four, if that's an issue.

EDIT: Oh, my apologies. Didn't realize parse_line got misformatted. Fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `commands[i]` will resolve to a type `char *`, i.e. a pointer.

- If a pointer has a value other that NULL, it will be considered as TRUE.
- If the pointer is NULL, it will considered as FALSE.

for the condition checking.

Comment: Because the pointer is still an address, which is a non-zero integer, correct?

Comment: @CodeSammich Pretty much, except the `int` should be either `intptr_t` or `uintptr_t`

Answer (score 2):

Since `command[i]` refers to a `char *`, it is considered `1` if non-null and `0` if null.

Comment: Unless you change `null` to `NULL`, your answer is _technically_ wrong. :)

Answer (score 1):

In `C` any non-Zero value implies true. So for all char pointers whose value is not `0` the condition holds true.

If `commands[i] = NULL` - then this condition becomes false in `C`.

[Null pointer](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/NULL/)